# excel_sheets(path = x) searches for a file that does not exist

Tags: r, excel

I am writing a script that will combine tables from many different excel spreadsheets into a single spreadhseet. The steps I take:

1) create a list of all excel spreadsheets of interest
2) for each spreadsheet - check if the relevant "sheet" is in that spreadsheet
3) ...eventually (not at this stage yet)...select the relevant cells from each sheet and import them into a single dataframe (because they should all have the same headings...)

I have got to stage 2) only because I receive an error that seems to suggest that the script is trying to open a file that does not exist.

```
# create a list of all folders at the next level that contain all of the 
excel spreadsheets
cluster_folders <- dir(path = in_path, pattern = "GLU", all.files = FALSE,
                          full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
                          ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = 
FALSE)

all_plots <- list()

# iteratively loop through them
for(fld in cluster_folders){
  # create a list of all excel files
  plots <- list.files(path = file.path(in_path, fld), pattern = "GLU", all.files = FALSE,
         full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE, ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)
  all_plots <- append(all_plots, plots)  
}
print(all_plots)

# for each excel file perform a check that ensures each excel spreadsheet 
has the a sheet that contains stem measurements
for(plot in all_plots){
  # file name is 
  print(plot)
  shts <- excel_sheets(path = plot)
  #print(shts)
  sht_num <- match('Field Form - F5b - Trees',shts)
  # now we navigate to that sheet and check that all the information is 
  there
  #data <- read.xls(plot, sheet="Field Form - F5b - Trees")
}
```

This script is working for all files except 2.

The error message that I recieve is:  Evaluation error: zip file 'C:/ ...../Survey/GLU0223537/~$GLU0223537 plot 1.xlsx' cannot be opened.

...when I look into this folder, no such file exists. 1) it used to but then I re-saved it to .xls (because all the files that are working fine are .xls) and 2) I removed it completely.

Any advice appreciated. Thank you in advance

Becky

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your file system rather than with your code per se. As a kludge, perhaps you can filter your list of file names so that you only iterate over the `.xls` files in it.

Comment: thank you for this - a good idea to keep things moving. ...and while I find the time to figure out the issue. Thank you for your thoughts and time